# Comparing date and time with acceptable differences

Tags: java, selenium

Say I have 2 strings containing date as follow

```
String A = 25 Nov 2015 10.50 GMT+6
String B = 25 Nov 2015 10.45 GMT+6
```

How do I make it so that it is acceptable to have a differences of several minutes between the two date strings? I can't use *Selenium* to assert between the two strings as it would definitely throw me asserting error.

Comment: Those are not valid GMT offset values. The number after `GMT` must be 2 digits (`+06`), 4 digits (`+0600`), or with colon (`+06:00`).

Answer (score 2):

Parse the strings, then compare the milliseconds and apply a threshold.

But first, you have to fix those bad GMT offsets.

```
String a = "25 Nov 2015 10.50 GMT+6";
String b = "25 Nov 2015 10.45 GMT+6";

// fix bad GMT
a = a.replaceFirst(" GMT\\+(\\d)\\b", " GMT+0$1");
b = b.replaceFirst(" GMT\\+(\\d)\\b", " GMT+0$1");

// parse dates
SimpleDateFormat datefmt = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH.mm 'GMT'X");
Date dateA = datefmt.parse(a);
Date dateB = datefmt.parse(b);

// detect difference
long diffInMillis = Math.abs(dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime());
if (diffInMillis < 5 * 60 * 1000) {
    // all is good
} else {
    // bad: 5 or more minutes apart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the below comparator to compare roughly equal dates. You can decide the delta for two dates being equal while instantiating the comparator.

```
public class RoughlyEqualDates implements Comparator<String> {

    int acceptableDelta = 300000; // 5 minutes
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");//choose appropriate format here
    RoughlyEqualDates(int deltaInMins){//configurable delta
        this.acceptableDelta = deltaInMins*60*1000;
    }
    public int compare(String date1, String date2) {
        long d1,d2;
        try {
            d1 = format.parse(date1).getTime();
            d2 = format.parse(date2).getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }

        if(Math.abs(d1-d2)<=acceptableDelta){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return d1>d2?1:-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods suggested are nice, though I believe you must be getting these strings from the `Date` itself in which case why not try this :

```
Date d1 = <source for String A>;
Date d2 = <source for String B>;
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

//here are the differences
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

//for your case 
if(diffMinutes <= acceptableDifference) //I' fine with it
else //Give me something else
```